# selecting values from a table and counting them but not include that value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a number of things from a table such as name, address, town and then show the number of times that town appears e. Mr A, the street, town, 3.
I want to produce something like

```
Personid    Forename    Surname Groupid count
1   John    Bloggs  1   2
2   Josh    Bloggs  1   2
3   Bert    Bloggs  1   2
4   Owen    Jones   2   1
5   Jack    Rose    3   1
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by original value ?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it? It would make the question much clearer.

Comment: Do you need an alias for the column name? So it's not showing `a.town` and `count(a.town)` ?

Comment: Hi after reveiwing my code I dont think i am along the right lines. i have the table below Personid Forename Surname Groupid
1 John Bloggs 1
2 Josh Bloggs 1
3 Bert  Bloggs 1
4 Owen Jones 2
5 Jack Rose 3
and i want to achieve something like Personid Forename Surname Groupid count
1 John Bloggs 1 2
2 Josh Bloggs 1 2
3 Bert  Bloggs 1 2
4 Owen Jones 2 1
5 Jack Rose 3 1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). For an SQL question, it is important to include the DBMS you're using (you now say it is MS SQL Server, and I've updated the tags for you). It is also important that you include representative subsets of the schemas of the tables (table names are depressingly often omitted), and some sample data, and the expected output from the sample data. Ideally, you should include an MCVE ([MCVE]), showing your current output and explaining what's wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try working with this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/591ea6/1
Not sure If I understand completely what you need

```
SELECT Personid
    ,Forename
    ,Surname
    ,z.Groupid
    ,c.count
FROM TableZ z
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT groupid
        ,count(groupid) AS [count]
    FROM TableZ
    GROUP BY groupid
    ) c ON c.Groupid = z.Groupid
```

Comment: That looks about right i will try it.  Thanks for everyones help and i'll review everything suggested before posting again.